# Selenium WebDriver zoom in/out not working Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have tried to zoom out the page with following code

```
public static void zoomOutPage(int value) throws AWTException {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    }
}
```

This script works well in local execution, but when I am trying to execute it from Jenkins, it is not working.

Also, I have tried the below script, but it does not work in local as well as Jenkins.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
element .sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SUBTRACT));
```

By using Actions class,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(element, Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ADD, Keys.NULL).perform();
```

Comment: When you say that its not working, what do you mean exactly? Is it just not performing the action, is it getting an error at all? If there is an error can you provide the error message so we can help debug :)

Comment: There is no error in the execution. It is not performing that particular action in Jenkins execution

Comment: It doesn't look like a Jenkins issue to me, but the environment that you're trying to run the script on. Can you specify what kind of node you're using to run the script and it if differs from your local machine?

Comment: We are using windows in both local and Jenkins (AWS workspace). I have used Jenkins master node to execute this operation